# What is the JAR for com.ibm.wsspi.security.web.saml.UserMapping Interface

Tags: java, websphere, single-sign-on, interceptor

I am trying to plug in the Default ACS interceptor in IBM with custom implementation of com.ibm.wsspi.security.web.saml.UserMapping, but am unable to find the JAR file containing this interface.
Also, is this functionality (custom implementation/plugging-in of UserMapping) supported by IBM WAS 8.0.5?

Any pointers/information would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For compilation purposes, the interface is located in WAS_HOME/dev/was_public.jar (WAS_HOME/dev is the location of all WebSphere API/SPI classes to build against).  At runtime, it will be loaded from WAS_HOME/plugins/com.ibm.wsfp.main.jar.  Technically, "WAS 8.0.5" does not exist, but I assume you are referring to either 8.0.0.5 or 8.5.X, and it's in the same place in both releases.

I believe the answer to the last part of that question is "yes, it is supported", although I'd need to defer to others on the details or docs.

Comment: Thanks Jarid.. Found the JAR in plugins directory. But now it is giving error for com.ibm.websphere.security.UserMappingException. Is the AJR file for this located in plugins directory as well? If so, which one is it?

Comment: The "AJR" in the above comment was a typo, i meant "JAR"

Comment: Found it. Its "com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar" :-)